# differences between bound and unbound delegates in CLI/C++

Tags: delegates, c++-cli

Whats the difference between bound and unbound delegates?

heres how you create delegates of both types:

```cpp
// bound delegate declaration
public delegate void Handler(int value);
// create a bound delegate
Handler^ handler = gcnew Handler(HandlerClass::Fun1);

// unbound delegate declaration
public delegate void UBHandler(ThisClass^, int value); 
// create an unbound delegate
UBHandler^ ubh = gcnew UBHandler(&ThisClass::Sum);
```

these are nearly the same. then, you can create constructors for bound delegates that consist of two parameters:

```cpp
HandlerClass^ obj = gcnew HandlerClass;
Handler^ handler2 = gcnew Handler (obj, & HandlerClass::Fun3);
```

it means that you can use this particular delegate to invoke a function that is not static (is an instance). but then you can do the same with unbound delegates. Here’s how you might call the ubh delegate:

```cpp
ThisClass^ obj = gcnew ThisClass(99.0);
ubh(obj, 5);
```

---

so whats the point of having both types?

```
// code for HandlerClass
public ref class HandlerClass
{
  public:

  static void Fun1(int m)
  { Console::WriteLine(L”Function1 called with value {0}”, m); }
  static void Fun2(int m)
  { Console::WriteLine(L”Function2 called with value {0}”, m); }
  void Fun3(int m)
  { Console::WriteLine(L”Function3 called with value {0}”, m+value); }
  void Fun4(int m)
  { Console::WriteLine(L”Function4 called with value {0}”, m+value); }

  HandlerClass():value(1){}
  HandlerClass(int m):value(m){}

  protected:

  int value;
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `HandlerClass`? Is `Fun1` static?

Comment: Then it's fairly clear, isn't it -- one version is for free functions, and one is for (non-static) member functions.

Comment: but bound delegates can handle both static and non-static functions, so i cant see what unbound delegates are for.. i cant find any info..

Comment: I don't know C++/CLI, but by the looks of it I'd say that an unbound delegate with a static member functions is a bit useless, while an unbound delegate with a non-static member function would be extremely useful, and not the same at all as a bound delegate.

Comment: Does the notion of "bound" and "unbound" delegate even exist, or is that just a word you use privately? Do you have a reference to an MSDN page? Otherwise this really just looks like free function versus instance+PTMF to me... In fact, delegates *are* really quite similar to pointers-to-member-function, and you can do something very similar with `std::function`.

Comment: no, they really do exist - i have read about them in Ivor Hortons book - "beginning visual c++ 2010".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the exact time the target object value is generated.  With a bound delegate it is generated when you create the delegate object and it is forever unchanging after that.  An unbound delegate doesn't store the object reference, it is generated at the time the delegate is invoked.  The same delegate can then be used to invoke the target method with different objects.

Unbound delegates are a match with the syntax of C++ member function pointers.  There is no direct equivalent for bound delegates in C++.

Comment: Well, the match for bound delegates would be a `pair<T * const, R (T::*)(Args...)>` I suppose...

Comment: I think a closer match for bound delegates would be `std::bind(&foo::bar, obj, _1, _2, _3)`.